# Deployment of WPF application with Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have built a WPF application with Entity Framework 4.1. The database of this application resides in another server. I have published the application. When I try to run the "Click Once Deployment" in another computer which does not have SQL Server and Entity Framework installed but it has .Net Framework 4.5, the application crashes at the point where it tries to access the database. 
How do I correctly deploy this application?

Comment: Try SQL server compact edtion